# problem loading Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.arm.dll on dotnetcore3.1 running on 32 bit Raspbian

Tags: linux, .net-core, arm, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to run a Visual Studio solution for dotnetcore3.1 on a Raspberry PI 4 with Raspbian as OS. Publishing to and running on Windows is no problem at all.
Also, the application starts without problems on the Raspberry, but crashes very soon with the message that it can't load a dll or its dependencies. Using LD_DEBUG=libs, it becomes clear that the **load problem** occurs with **Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.arm.dll**. This dll comes with a Nuget package to my solution and it is found on the Raspberry in the lib search path as well. Copying the dll from windows into the search path does not solve the problem.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.*.dll is native windows dll. It require windows to run, source code not available. Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native exists for x86/x64/arm (all for windows). https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native

From description:
Native implementation of PDB file reader and writer.
Supported Platforms:

- Windows x86
- Windows amd64
- Windows arm

For Windows arm64 (Surface Pro X) not available now https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/issues/324

DiaSymReader depends on Windows COM and MS Dia https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/debug-interface-access-sdk?view=vs-2019

For parsing pdb you can try use open source MS pdb parsers, e.g. for rust https://github.com/willglynn/pdb

pdb can read PDBs anywhere. There's no dependency on Windows, on the DIA SDK, or on the target's native byte ordering.

Sentry symbolic application https://github.com/getsentry/symbolic uses pdb crate for parsing different symbols formats. Also has C ABI, so you can create .net wrapper with dllimport.

Great mozilla stack-fixing (symbolication) utility based on sentry symbolic create:
https://blog.mozilla.org/nnethercote/2020/04/15/better-stack-fixing-for-firefox/
https://github.com/mozilla/fix-stacks